# Not sure which SQL join to use

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables (AllClients & AllActivities) and need to retrieve the following information:

I need a list of clients where there are no associated activities.

Here are my tables with some fake data to help explain what I'm looking for:

[image: http://www.givingdirection.com/table.jpg]

I basically need the sql to retrieve Sam Johnson because there are no activities for him and he has a TypeCode of 'P'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a join

```
select *
from AllClients c
where TypeCode = 'P'
and not exists (select 1 from AllActivities a where a.LookupCode = c.LookupCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.*
from AllClients c 
left join AllActivities a on a.LoopupCode = c.LoopupCode 
where a.LoopupCode is null
and c.TypeCode = 'P'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   AllClients 
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM AllActivities WHERE AllActivities.lookUpCode = AllClients.lookUpCode) 
   AND TypeCode = 'P'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `IN` version is missing:

```
select *
from AllClients c
where TypeCode = 'P'
and LookupCode not in (select distinct LookupCode from AllActivities)
```